# Geting correct search result from two tables, when running my SQL query

Tags: mysql, select

I'm new here and new to SQL and programming in general.

I'm currently trying to see which cages are not reserved on specific datetimes. To do this, I'm looking at 2 tables at once: reservation and cage.

My tables look like this:

Reservation

```
Reserved_id | Cage_id |Start_date | End_date | Phone_number |
-------------------------------------------------------------
          1 |       1 |2017-05-10 |2017-05-17|12345678      |
          2 |       2 |2017-05-17 |2017-05-24|87654321      |
          3 |       3 |2017-08-14 |2017-08-17|87654321      |
          4 |       4 |2017-06-01 |2017-06-08|87651234      |
          5 |       5 |2017-06-15 |2017-06-22|87524308      |
          6 |       6 |2017-08-14 |2017-08-17|87524308      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cage

```
Cage_id | Cage_type | House_type |
----------------------------------
      1 | Udebur    | Rødt Hus   |
      2 | Indebur   | Grønt Hus  |
      3 | Ude- og In| Gult Hus   |
      4 | Indebur   | Gult Hus   |
      5 | Indebur   | Gult Hus   |
      6 | Udebur    | Rødt Hus   |
      7 | Ude- og In| Grønt Hus  |
      8 | Indebur   | Rødt Hus   |
      9 | Udebur    | Rødt Hus   |
----------------------------------
```

So far, when I'm running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cage.Cage_id, Cage.Cage_type, Cage.House_Name 
FROM Cage Right OUTER JOIN Reservation ON Cage.cage_id = Reservation.Cage_id
WHERE Reservation.Start_Date AND Reservation.End_Date NOT BETWEEN "2017-05-09" AND "2017-05-18";
```

I get the result:

```
Cage_ID |
--------|
2       |
3       |
4       |
5       |
6       |
--------
```

So, what do I need to change in my query to see which cages are NOT reserved between the two dates?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you cant "chain" columns in where clause so your `Reservation.Start_Date AND Reservation.End_Date` doesnt do what you expect it to do. You have to query each column separately.

Comment: The construct `Reservation.Start_Date AND Reservation.End_Date
NOT BETWEEN "2017-05-09" AND "2017-05-18"` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Cage c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Reservation r
                  WHERE c.cage_id = r.Cage_id AND
                        r.Start_date <= '2017-05-18' and
                        r.End_Date >= '2017-05-09'
                 );
```

This version checks that there is no reservation at all during the specified days (including the two end-points).

Comment: Thanks! This works out perfect, and does exactly what i want it to.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to correct the syntax for the date range conditions
2. You need to LEFT join the reservations and move the reservation date conditions in the ON clause.
3. Filter all the Cages without a Reservation

E.g:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Cage
LEFT JOIN Reservation ON 
    Cage.cage_id = Reservation.Cage_id AND 
    Reservation.Start_Date <= "2017-05-18" AND 
    Reservation.End_Date >= "2017-05-09"
WHERE Reservation.Reserved_id IS NULL
```

Comment: You could refactor parenthetical clause down to `Reservation.Start_Date <= "2017-05-18" AND Reservation.End_Date >= 2017-05-09"` like @Gordon did

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Cage_id 
FROM Cage c
LEFT JOIN Reservation r ON (c.Cage_id = r.Cage_id)
WHERE c.Cage_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: this will filter out all the cages once there is a record in reservation table. Unless you remove all the _expired_ records fron reservation table, this wont work. You have to check dates here.